# Cyclic inequalities involving the Gudermannian function and/or its inverse function

Tags: inequalities

After I've read the *Problem 4136* from [1], and I think (I've computed it in the same way that in the solutions) that the same statement is right for the following expression where $a,b$ and $c$ are real numbers $>0$ $$b\operatorname{gd}(a)+c\operatorname{gd}(b)+a\operatorname{gd}(c)<\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2},$$
where $\operatorname{gd}(x)$ denotes the Gudermannian function, see the Wikipedia [*Gudermannian function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function), I wodered what should be interesting or feasibles cyclic inequalities invovling particular values of the Gudermannian function and/or its inverse.

> **Question.** Can you create a cyclic inequality, with good mathematical content, involving an expression of particular values of the Gudermannian function and/or its inverse? **Many thanks.**

You can take the expression involving this/these special function/s in the way that you think that the resulting inequality has good mathematical content.

### References:

[1] Daniel Sitaru and Mihaly Bencze, *Problem 4136*, Crux Mathematicorum, Volume 43, Number 4, April 2017.

Comment: The web page of Crux Mathematicorum (I believe that is a journal of the Canadian Mathematical Society) is https://cms.math.ca/crux from which you can see its Digital Archive.

Comment: it would be nice if you retype here the problem 4136 and specify what exactly holds for your expression

Comment: I'm sorry @FedorPetrov but I do it with all respect to the mentioned journal and authors, that is a free online journal: search for Crux Mathematicorum and you can find the problem in the corresponding section of solved problems. On the other hand I did the calculations for my expression and I can deduce the same inequality of the statement of the Problem 4136.

Comment: @user142929 if you can't be bothered to link to it, why would anyone here be bothered to answer your question?!

Comment: @user142929 ok and what is disrespectful in citing the statement of the problem here?!

Comment: All, of course I don't think that mathematicians do a disrespectful in citing mathematics in this site MO. I think that my problem is good stated as was cited the bibliogrphy. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function#Alternative_definitions), $\text{gd}(x)=2\arctan e^x-\pi/2<\pi/2$  for real $x$. So, 
$$b\,\text{gd}(a)+c\,\text{gd}(b)+a\,\text{gd}(c)
<\frac\pi2(b+c+a)\le\frac{\pi\sqrt3}2\,\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2},$$
by the arithmetic mean--quadratic mean inequality. Thus, we have the inequality in question.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.